# Android Kotlin - Saving Preferences (key value pair) - not working for me

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying various simple Android Kotlin examples, to save some persistent data in my app.
To  start, I am using a straight forward example of writing one key-value pair, and reading it back.
here's my code, in my activity's OnCreate()

```
val sharedPrefFile = "MyPrefFile"
val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
fun setPref()
{
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    val myName = "Elvis"
    editor.putString("nameFirst_key", myName)
}
fun getPref()
{
    val myName = sharedPreferences.getString("nameFirst_key", "no_name")
 }
getPref()
setPref()
getPref()
```

I would expect the first getPref() call to read "no_name", which it does.
However, I was hoping the second getPref() call would read "Elvis", but it doesn't - it reads "no_name".

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks

Garrett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `commit()` or `apply()` on `editor`, so the edits are not taking effect. This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

So, `setPref()` should be:

```kotlin
fun setPref()
{
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    val myName = "Elvis"
    editor.putString("nameFirst_key", myName).apply()
}
```